# Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+c^2}}\le\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, summation, radicals, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

For positive real numbers with  $a+b+c=abc$ prove that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+c^2}}\le\frac{3}{2}$$

I made the substitution $a=\tan(\alpha), b = \tan(\beta), c= \tan(\gamma)$ with the constraint $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$

My inequality reduces to proving,

$$\cos^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\beta)+\cos^2(\gamma) \le\frac32$$

But I am stuck on it. Any help with either inequality would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you mean $|\cos(\alpha)|+|\cos(\beta)|+|\cos(\gamma)|\leq\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, reduces to $\sum \cos$ not squared. Then just a standard Jensen's argument. ;)

Comment: wow, I cannot believe I missed the square root. This is not even a noob mistake. Anyway thanks. +1

Comment: Although I am not sure I understand your Jensen's inequality point. $\cos$ isn't convex on $0$ to $\pi$

Comment: Oh I am sorry, it is. I dont know what's happening to me. :p  answer accepted.

Comment: Since cos is concave on $[0,\frac\pi2]$ and convex on $[\frac\pi2,\pi]$, the Jensen's argument requires a bit of care.  Since $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$, at most one of the three is greater than $\frac\pi2$, so wlog, $\alpha,\beta\in[0,\frac\pi2]$.  Then $\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta)+\cos(\gamma)\le2\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}2)+\cos(\gamma)=2\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})-\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\frac32-2(\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})-\frac12)^2\le\frac32$.

Comment: And, btw, this inequality is exercise 6.11 in Steele's *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class*; he credits it to the 1998 Korean National Olympiad.

Comment: Oh, wait.  You don't need to worry about $[\frac\pi2,\pi]$ because the angles are in $\arctan([0,\infty))=[0,\frac\pi2)$... which also addresses @MarioGallegos's point about the absolute values.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk yes the source where I found it also credits it to the korean olympiad.

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{abc}{a+b+c}+a^2}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{a(a+b)(a+c)}}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{bc}{(a+b)(a+c)}}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b}{a+b}+\frac{c}{a+c}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b}{a+b}+\frac{a}{a+b}\right)=\frac{3}{2}.$$
Done!