# proof of inequality perhaps using trigonometric identity

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I need help on the following problem.

Let $x,y,z$ be the positive real numbers and satisfy $x+y+z=xyz$

then,

$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}\leq\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$

I tried with $x=tan\alpha,y=tan\beta,z=tan\gamma$ and LHS reduses
to

$sin\alpha+sin\beta+sin\gamma$ but I don't know how to utilize $x+y+z=xyz$

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi k\iff x+y+z=xyz$, indeed,one can separate $\tan \gamma$

Comment: http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/demonstrate-that-triangle-abc-sina-sinb-sinc-lt-3-180145

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/977358